# Java + jackson parsing error Unrecognized character escape

Tags: java, json, jackson, http-post, parse-error

I need to do a POST json string , using HttpClient. Following will be the code i have. From the other end the Json is mapped to an object.

```
HttpClient client = HttpClientBuilder.create().build();
HttpPost post = new HttpPost(url);
String jsonData = "{ \"provider\" : null , \"password\" : \"a\", \"userid\" : \"mlpdemo\\mlpdemoins\" }";
post.setEntity(new ByteArrayEntity(         jsonData.toString().getBytes("UTF8")));
HttpResponse response = client.execute(post);
```

Here all others are correctly mapping expect the userId. Here the problem is with the backward slash(**mlpdemo\mlpdemins**). I guess. If I send a single string as the user id it will be mapped without any issues.
Eg:-

```
String jsonData = "{ \"provider\" : null , \"password\" : \"a\", \"userid\" : \"mlpdemoins\" }";
```

This works .

But I need this (**mlpdemo\mlpdemins**)to be sent through the POSt. Please help me out.

```
String jsonData = "{ \"provider\" : null , \"password\" : \"a\", \"userid\" : \"mlpdemo\\mlpdemoins\" }";
```

Here is the exception Im getting.

```
com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonParseException: Unrecognized character escape 'm' (code 109)
 at [Source: java.io.InputStreamReader@29f0a0a2; line: 1, column: 62]
BadRequestException (0ea35150-f33a-4932-a31e-8a1048af53ad): 400 Bad Request, com.strategicgains.restexpress.serialization.DeserializationException: com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonParseException: Unrecognized character escape 'm' (code 109)
 at [Source: java.io.InputStreamReader@29f0a0a2; line: 1, column: 62]
    at com.strategicgains.restexpress.Request.getBodyAs(Request.java:165)
    at com.strategicgains.restexpress.Request.getBodyAs(Request.java:181)
```

Comment: Try escaping the backslash with one or more backslash `\"mlpdemo\\\mlpdemoins\"`. Not sure but give it a try. Sorry if I am wrong

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`mlpdemo\mlpdemoins` is an invalid string you can't use it in JSON . But you can use `mlpdemo\\mlpdemoins` easily.

below code works fine for me :

```
String jsonData = "{ \"provider\" : null , \"password\" : \"a\", \"userid\" : \"mlpdemo\\\\mlpdemoins\" }";

ObjectMapper mapper=new ObjectMapper();

System.out.println(mapper.readTree(jsonData));
```

It will produce this output JSON :

```
{"provider":null,"password":"a","userid":"mlpdemo\\mlpdemoins"}
```

Answer (score 26):

Set your mapper

```
mapper.configure(JsonParser.Feature.ALLOW_BACKSLASH_ESCAPING_ANY_CHARACTER, true);
```

Comment: Where to write it?

Comment: In my version of jackson 2.9.9, the JsonParser is missing

Comment: Need to write in ObjectMapper Configuration.

Comment: **Deprecated.** Since 2.10 use [JsonReadFeature.ALLOW_BACKSLASH_ESCAPING_ANY_CHARACTER](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-core/javadoc/2.10/com/fasterxml/jackson/core/json/JsonReadFeature.html#ALLOW_BACKSLASH_ESCAPING_ANY_CHARACTER) instead.

Answer (score 6):

Since version *2.10* (released Sep, 2019), `JsonParser.Feature.ALLOW_BACKSLASH_ESCAPING_ANY_CHARACTER` has been deprecated, together with some other properties:

> @deprecated Since 2.10 use {@link com.fasterxml.jackson.core.json.JsonReadFeature#ALLOW_BACKSLASH_ESCAPING_ANY_CHARACTER} instead

While the properties at the time still exist in the current version (*2.11.3*), it has [actually been removed from the GIT master branch](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-core/blob/master/src/main/java/com/fasterxml/jackson/core/JsonParser.java), suggesting that it will probably be removed when version *3.0.0* is released.

The correct way to configure this property is instead by using [JsonReadFeature](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-core/blob/master/src/main/java/com/fasterxml/jackson/core/json/JsonReadFeature.java) instead. Instead of creating an `ObjectMapper` and call `configure()` on it, use [`JsonMapper`](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-databind/blob/master/src/main/java/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/json/JsonMapper.java) and its `builder()` method:

```
ObjectMapper mapper = JsonMapper.builder()
    .enable(JsonReadFeature.ALLOW_BACKSLASH_ESCAPING_ANY_CHARACTER)
    .build();
```

This returns a `JsonMapper`, which is a sub class of `ObjectMapper`, with the property enabled.

---

The related GitHub issue can be found [here](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-core/issues/467), and [this issue](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-core/issues/586) suggests some alternatives on how to achieve the configuration.

Comment: I'd like to thank you for providing links inline to the classes in question. More importantly, your code snippet worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

In my case I was using Spring so setting this property in the `application.yml` did the job:

```yaml
spring:
  jackson:
    parser:
      allow-backslash-escaping-any-character: true
```

This GitHub comment was helpful: https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-core/issues/586#issuecomment-672199588