# SpringBoot emoji input

Tags: spring, spring-boot, emoji

I have a `SpringBoot` application. On one of the `POST` endpoints, in the body I want a field that can contain `emoji`.

In my request object I have the following field:

`private final String name;`

In the body of my request I have the following input:

`"name" : "Hello, playground \Ud83d\Ude0a \Ud83e\Udd21\Ud83d\Udc68\U200d\Ud83c\Udf73 \U2663\Ufe0f"`

which contains some emojis.

The exception I get is:

`com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: Unrecognized character escape 'U' (code 85)`

and

`Caused by: com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonParseException: Unrecognized character escape 'U' (code 85)`

I tried to set the following flag on my object mapper with no luck:

`.configure(JsonParser.Feature.ALLOW_BACKSLASH_ESCAPING_ANY_CHARACTER, true)`

Any ideas?

Comment: Maybe escape non-ascii like in https://stackoverflow.com/a/23129089/9705485 ?

Comment: @RyanDawson it didn't work :( :( Still throws the same error. I'm pretty sure there should be a way for SpringBoot to support unicode characters...

Comment: More specifically jackson. Depending on how it's being formed it might need double-backslash https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30187530/java-jackson-parsing-error-unrecognized-character-escape

Comment: I think I found it... The mobile client was sending `\Ude0a` , while jackson needs the U to be lowercase :p :p